# mySQL query with HAVING gives me an error. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query I have this error message on phpmydamin: Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'having clause'

My column name is `timestamp`

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
hash
) AS total
FROM behaviour
HAVING total =1 and date(timestamp) = curdate()
```

How to get the number of hash for today?

Comment: There may be spaces before or after the column name. Please check.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Return one row with the value 1 (if it exists for current date)?

Comment: @jarlh In the behaviour table, some hash values appear more than 1 time. other hash values appear only 1 time. i want to count the hash rows that appear only 1 time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `where`.  And parentheses are not appropriate for `select distinct` (`distinct` is not a function).  I suspect that you intend:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hash) AS total
FROM behaviour
WHERE date(timestamp) = curdate();
```

It is better to write the `WHERE` clause without using a function on the column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hash) AS total
FROM behaviour
WHERE timestamp >= curdate() AND timestamp < date_add(curdate, interval 1 day);
```

Although more complicated, it allows the database engine to use an index on `behaviour(timestamp)` (or better yet, on `behaviour(timestamp, hash)`.

EDIT:

If you want the `hash` that only appear once, one method is a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select hash
      from behaviour
      where timestamp >= curdate() AND timestamp < date_add(curdate, interval 1 day)
      group by hash
      having count(*) = 1
     );
```

Comment: thank you, but let me rephrase it. In the behaviour table, some hash must be appeared more than 1 time. others appear only 1 time. i want to count the hash that appear only 1 time, not everything

Comment: so with this you are counting the unique has rows. I want to count the hash rows that appear today

Answer (score 0):

To count the hash values only existing once:

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select hash
    from behavior
    where date(timestamp) = curdate()
    group by hash
    having count(*) = 1
) dt
```

The inner select (derived table) will return the hash values only existing once. The outer select will count those rows.